# php compare current date with dates stored in database

Tags: php

I am trying coding a php script where i want to extract a date field from a database table,store this date compare it with todays. To see if the data. from database has passed or not compared to todays date.

1. the code i have written for this functionality looks like its not working
2. I think i am getting the date() format wrong.
3. I am not to sure about the logic if statments.

php

```
$sql="SELECT enddate FROM campaigns WHERE id=".$data['camp'];
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if(date("Y-m-d") > $result){
        exit;
        echo "Success";
    }
    elseif(date("Y-m-d") < $result){
        return true;
        echo "Failure";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtotime()`

```
while($info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if(strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) > strtotime($result)){
        exit;
        echo "Success";
    }
    elseif(strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) < strtotime($result)){
        return true;
        echo "Failure";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
if(date("Y-m-d") > $info['enddate']) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Youl could just let MySQL worry about it.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),enddate) FROM campaigns WHERE id=".$data['camp']
```

That will return the number of days between the two dates. [See the manual for `DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query :

```
$sql="SELECT (CASE WHEN DATE(NOW()) > enddate THEN 'success' ELSE 'failed' END) AS mystatus FROM campaigns WHERE id=".$data['camp'];
```

Then you just need to call **mystatus** column from the query.

Answer (score 0):

I spend lot of time to compare only dates and i found a solution like this

Always set format like **date('Y-m-d')**

```
$dateTo='2016-08-07';
if(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateTo)) > date('Y-m-d')){
   echo 'yes';
}else{
   echo 'no';
}
```