# How do I compare two dates without receiving errors everywhere?

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I am pretty new to PHP. I need to compare two dates in an 'if' statement but nothing seems to be working. Please for the love of all that is holy, someone please tell me what is the right way to do it.
Context: I'm trying to compare the current date to the date found in ($row["EffectiveDate"]), and if the current date is later than the date in ($row["EffectiveDate"]), it should trigger the if statement. It is supposed to trigger the first time it loops, but it doesn't. It will loop through the whole SQL result and then puke out nothing.

1st Attempt:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM gst ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC";
            $result = $conn->query($qry);
            if($result->num_rows >0)
            {
                $taxratenotdeterminedyet = True;
                while($taxratenotdeterminedyet == True)
                {
                    $row = $result->fetch_array();
                    if((strtotime($row["EffectiveDate"]) < date("Y-m-d")))                                               
                    {
                        $taxratenotdeterminedyet = False;
                        $currentTaxRate = $row["TaxRate"];
                        //$currentTaxRate = 8;
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

1st Attempt Result: I have no errors at all, but the loop went past the array that I wanted, which means the date comparison didn't work. It looped past all the entries and only activated when it reached an empty array.

2nd Attempt:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM gst ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC";
            $result = $conn->query($qry);
            if($result->num_rows >0)
            {
                $taxratenotdeterminedyet = True;
                while($taxratenotdeterminedyet == True)
                {
                    $row = $result->fetch_array();
                    if((new DateTime() > new DateTime($row["EffectiveDate"])))                                               
                    {
                        $taxratenotdeterminedyet = False;
                        $currentTaxRate = $row["TaxRate"];
                        //$currentTaxRate = 8;
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

2nd Attempt Result: Never-Ending List of Errors

3rd Attempt :

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM gst ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC";
            $result = $conn->query($qry);
            if($result->num_rows >0)
            {
                $taxratenotdeterminedyet = True;
                while($taxratenotdeterminedyet == True)
                {
                    $row = $result->fetch_array();
                    $format = "y-m-d";
                    $date1  = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $row["EffectiveDate"]);
                    $date2  = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, "2021-1-29");
                    if($date2 > $date1)                                               
                    {
                        $taxratenotdeterminedyet = False;
                        $currentTaxRate = $row["TaxRate"];
                        //$currentTaxRate = 8;
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

3rd Attempt Result :
Notice: Undefined index: ProductImage in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 60

Notice: Undefined index: ProductID in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 62

Notice: Undefined index: Name in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 62

Notice: Undefined index: ProductID in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined index: Price in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 64

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: ProductID in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined index: Total in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 90

Notice: Undefined index: ProductID in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 97

Notice: Undefined index: ProductID in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 107

Notice: Undefined index: Name in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 108

Notice: Undefined index: Price in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 109

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 110

Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 111

Notice: Undefined index: Total in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 114

Notice: Undefined index: ProductImage in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php on line 60

Comment: What is the date format of `$row["EffectiveDate"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46583891/9139447) answer, you can try this on your 1st attempt:

```
if(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row["EffectiveDate"])) < date("Y-m-d"))
```